# IE 9 Rendering Problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem with Internet Explorer on my website ([My Website](http://www.gameralien.com/profile/1/glitchking/)).

The problem is under "Account Summary", the avatar is using absolute positioning. It works fine under Chrome and FireFox, yet for some reason it doesn't in IE 9 (compatible mode fails as well).

The avatar positions correctly when the page is loading, but exactly when the page finishes loading, the avatar shoots off to the right.

Here are some things I've tried and it still fails.

Removed all CSS from head
removed header/footer code
resized avatar
resized display block width/height
some other minor tweaks

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you have some code that changes the image into a span in IE, so the style that you have specified for the "Last active" span also applies to the avatar.

Add classes to the span and the image so that you can use those in the CSS selectors, so that you don't use the element names in the selectors.

Comment: Thank you for response, could you narrow down exactly which code it is?

Comment: I suspect it's the PNG fix, maybe IE9 ignores the directive that should make it apply only to IE6 and below.

Comment: @Brandon: As Shadow Wizard says, it's most likely a PNG fix. It should only be applied to IE 6, but you need to change your CSS selectors anyway, otherwise it won't work in IE 6.

Comment: http://www.gameralien.com/includes/jscript.js was causing conflictions somewhere. I'll have to look into it.